# Save and load NSMutableArray - NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a `NSMutableArray` to `NSUserDefaults` then reload it and use it to populate the button labels.  Can someone please take a look and tell me what i am doing wrong here?

When I am loading the file to new array it appears empty. All of the buttons I am trying to set the titles to are in ibCollectionOutlet called buttons

```
-(void)save {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.pressCountArray forKey:@"savedFile"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)load{

    NSMutableArray *countArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"savedFile"] mutableCopy];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.pressCountArray count]; i++){
        self.pressCountArray[i] = countArray[i];
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.buttons count]; i++){
        UIButton *btn = self.buttons[i];
        int curCnt = [[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];

        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",curCnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: put breakpoint or NSlog the values before save and after , to know what is happening

Comment: How is pressCountArray declared and how do you set its contents? The first loop should be replaced with `self.pressCountArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"saveFile"] mutableCopy];

I would try to put a breakpoint in the save method and print the contents of [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] in the debugger.

Comment: Can you manually examine your user defaults or print it out before and after both methods? Maybe you'll find your error through that.

Comment: PressCountArray as 16 integers, between 1-3, when i use a break point after load my pressCountArray is empty?

Answer (score 4):

I think your array contains custom objects.
If that is the case then you should implement `NSCoding` protocol (for serialization and de-serialization) in your custom model class.

Implement the following NSCoding protocol methods in your class:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
```

After that save the data like:

```
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.pressCountArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:encodedObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedFile"]];
```

And retrieve the data like:

```
NSData *encodedObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedFile"]];
self.pressCountArray  = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
```

Comment: If that was true there would be an exception "attempt to insert non-property list object".  So this cannot be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not allocating `self.pressCountArray` during the load and are probably attempting to populate an empty array (in a fairly strange way).  Instead simply do:

```
-(void)load{

    self.pressCountArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"savedFile"] mutableCopy];

    NSAssert([self.pressCountArray count] == [self.buttons count], @"Array count mismatch");

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.buttons count]; i++){
        UIButton *btn = self.buttons[i];
        int curCnt = [[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];

        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",curCnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Note that you need to check that the correct number of array elements have been loaded.  I've used an `NSAssert` in the above code, but you probably need to return `NO` given it's probably something that can happen in production.

Comment: self.pressCountArray is empty when it is loaded still,

Comment: @burrGGG OK, so it looks like the array is not being stored in the `NSUserDefaults` object.